# Retain the value of an object after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

Following code deserializes Config.xml and loads the object values in a grid. The problem is that when I select a row it fires `GridCustomers_RowSelected` but config object is null. I understand it is due to the fact the each time I select a row, it posts back and forgets the values in config object.

One solution to this problem could be that I store config object in a session, or viewstate. Or I deserialize the object outside the `IsPostBack` block. I wonder is there any other better solution to retain the values in config object.

```
private Config config = null;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
       config = new Config();
       string file = @"C:\Config.xml";
       XmlData xmlData = new XmlData(file);
       config = xmlData.Deserialize();

       StoreCustomers.DataSource = config.Customers;
       StoreCustomers.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridCustomers_RowSelected(object sender, DirectEventArgs e) 
{ 
    string customerID = e.ExtraParams["ID"].ToString(); 
    string customerName = e.ExtraParams["Name"].ToString();

    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer = config.Customers.Where( a=> a.ID == customerID).SingleOrDefault();

    StoreCompanies.DataSource = customer.Companies;
    StoreCompanies.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Or I deserialize the object outside the IsPostBack

Do that, deserialize and create it outside the IsPostBack

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   config = new Config();
   string file = @"C:\Config.xml";
   XmlData xmlData = new XmlData(file);
   config = xmlData.Deserialize();

  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   { 
       StoreCustomers.DataSource = config.Customers;
       StoreCustomers.DataBind();
    }
}
```